# Integral through complex methods $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log \sin^{2}2\theta d\theta=4\int_{0}^{\pi}\log \sin\theta d\theta=-4\pi \log 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Using residue theorem show that: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log \sin^{2}2\theta d\theta=4\int_{0}^{\pi}\log \sin\theta d\theta=-4\pi \log 2$$

I cannot show even the first identity let alone the second one.

Can anyone show please how to calculate this integral using residue and the first identity?

**P.S.** I have solved bunch of integrals but have problems with this one.

Comment: The first equality is just a simple substitution $\theta=2t$. Afterwards, replace $t$ with $\theta$.

Comment: It's a bit of a nuanced argument. See, for example, page 160 of Ahlfors 3rd Ed. An easier alternative to residue theory is to use Jensen's Theorem.